# ClassCastException with XML parsing in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a problem with parsing some XML files in Android environment...
After starts my android app, I made some tests parsing XML under JAVA environment.

So, I wrote this code:

```
private void addMeta(Node n){
    String[] fields = {"src", "timestamp", "title", "kind", "ref", "crcData"};
    Element e = (Element)n.getChildNodes();
    //... more code
}
```

But, when using this in Android returns me a ClassCastException.

I was looking up to find the problem, and (as I can understand) the problem is the following:

Android is getting another kind of "NodeList" (the data type returned by "n.getChildNodes()". The data type Android is getting is: org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.NodeListImpl.

So, seeing that, I changed my code, from a direct casting to a method who does it. It's code is:

```
private org.w3c.dom.Element getElements(Node n){
    org.w3c.dom.NodeList nl = (org.w3c.dom.NodeList)n.getChildNodes();
    return (org.w3c.dom.Element)nl;
}
```

Then, I change "Element e = (Element)n.getChildNodes()" by "org.w3c.dom.Element e = this.getElements(n)"

But, inside "getElements" method, something strange happens...

"nl" is still getted as "org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.NodeListImpl", so I still getting a ClassCastException.

So, what I may have to get a "org.w3c.dom.NodeList" instead of a "org.apache..." NodeList?

Thanks you all, and sorry for my bad English... :s

Comment: Make sure you have correct imports on top of your class.

Comment: I think if I use the qualified name (org.w3c.dom.Element) is not necessary to made any import... Tomorrow I'll try to add the imports.

Comment: I checked the import, and are correctly imported (org.w3c.dom.Element, org.w3c.dom.NodeList, ...)

Answer (score 0):

The NodeList is pointing to 0 or more Nodes so it cant be cast to a Node/Element directly. Depending on the structure, the children could include elements as well as attrbutes of the node.

To get to a particular node from a NodeList, you'd have to iterate over it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
   Node item = nodeList.item(i);
   // if this matches the element name you're 
   // looking for then return else continue
}
```

The other option is to see whether the given Node is an element and then query using getElementsByTagName("name") and then iterate over it to find the right one and then return it.

```
if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
   Element e = (Element) node;
   NodeList elements = e.getElementsByTagName("name_of_tag_you_want");
   // process node list and find the right one and return

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer.

But, when parsing my XML I'm taking care to get always nodes with children (so, getChildNodes will always return a NodeList).

Before calling "addMeta", I Iterate over the nodes, using some functions:

The start point is "fill" method:

```
public boolean fill(String[] curr, String file){
    try{
        Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new java.io.StringReader(file)));

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        for(int i=0;i<curr.length;i++)
            this.treat((doc.getElementsByTagName(curr[i])), curr[i]);
    }catch(ParserConfigurationException e){
        this.error = Strings.PARSEEXCEPTION.getValue();
        this.exception = e;
        return false;
    }catch(SAXException e){
        this.error = Strings.SAXEXCEPTION.getValue();
        this.exception = e;
        return false;
    }catch(IOException e){
        this.error = Strings.IOEXCEPTION.getValue();
        this.exception = e;
        return false;
    }

    return this.check();
}
```

Then, "treat" method:

```
private void treat(NodeList nl, String kind){
    for(int i=0;i<nl.getLength();i++)
        this.add(nl.item(i), kind);
}
```

"add" method:

```
private void add(Node n, String kind){
    if(kind.equals("meta"))
        this.addMeta(n);
            //... more code
```

And, in "addMeta", all the items I'm trying to get has children. A basic structure of the XML I'm trying to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns="myweb/myxmlns.xsd">
<meta>
    <generator>
        <src>62.83.204.127</src>
        <timestamp>1359743849</timestamp>
    </generator>
    <doc>
        <title>Title</title>
        <kind>m</kind>
    </doc>
    <ext>
        <authUser>
            <ref>David-Solé-González-1</ref>
        </authUser>
    </ext>
    <crcData>2e021a71461e5a1bf6b71a5779446857a1d6b073</crcData>
</meta>
</Document>
```

And, of course **It works well in JAVA**, but in android is giving a ClassCastException...